# Layman explanation and demonstration of positive lightning

Tags: education, home-experiment, lightning

Inspired by the thunderstorm overhead, and after reading the question and answers [Voltage and current of positive lightning](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28560/voltage-and-current-of-positive-lightning) - what is an effective means to explain this phenomenon to a layman?

Also, as demonstrations are more often than not a better way of explanation, how could positive lightning be safely and meaningfully demonstrated?

Comment: For your last question: Just create a Faraday cage with small enough grip size. That is enough for protection.